# Bootstrap Accordion within Kendo Popup Custom Editor Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Bootstrap Accordion within a Kendo Popup Custom Editor Template for a Kendo Grid.

It is however causing me some issues with the accordion.

1) When expanding an accordion 'panel', the accordion over expands and snaps back to fit the content.

2) The accordion headers don't have the 'hand' cursor on mouse over, instead they have the text cursor.

This is my HTML:

```
    <style>

    .popup {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }


    .k-window-content * {                   /* Added to fix the Bootstrap within Kendo border-box vs content-box box-sizing property issue. */   
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>

<div class="container popup">

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <!-- First Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
                    enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Second Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseTwo">
                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
                    enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Third Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseThree">
                    Collapsible Group Item #3
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
                    enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? My guess is the fact the accordion is within a Kendo popup means that some styling is being affected. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the css rules from this link "https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#nest-widgets-and-bootstrap-grid-layout". In order to use Bootstrap classes inside a kendo-window or dialog and make it work as expected you should add the rules mentioned in the article. I don't know if it will fix your problem but most css issues come from this.

Comment: have you tried adding the css rules mentioned in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to change cursor style:

```
.panel-heading:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Where you need model popup?

Comment: the accordion is within a kendo popup

Comment: i'm don't work in kendo before so sorry ,  cursor worked or no?